# ORA-24247: network access denied by access control list (ACL)

Tags: sql, oracle, email, ora-24247

I seem to be getting the above error, and I tried sending a mail over the intranet as well, but of no use.
Does the above error message mean that my mail program is correct, and the problem is with the restriction imposed on an user, by the database administrator?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Taken from http://www.dba-oracle.com/t_ora_24247_network_access_denied_by_access_control_list_tips.htm:

> **ORA-24247**: network access denied by access control list (ACL)
>
> **Cause**: No access control list (ACL) has been assigned to the target
>   host or the privilege necessary to access the target host has not been
>   granted to the user in the access control list.
>
> **Action**: Ensure that an access control list (ACL) has been assigned to
>   the target host and the privilege necessary to access the target host
>   has been granted to the user.
>
> Your application will encounter an ORA-24247 error if it relies on one
>   of the network packages and no proper ACL has been created. For the
>   use of the following packages it is mandatory to have an ACL for the
>   application user in place in 11g:
>
> UTL_TCP
>
> UTL_SMTP
>
> UTL_MAIL
>
> UTL_HTTP
>
> UTL_INADDR

Also read the following [post](http://blog.whitehorses.nl/2010/03/17/oracle-11g-access-control-list-and-ora-24247/) by Ian Hoogeboom

Comment: Is there anything from the above that a user could do without the intervention of the DBA?

Comment: The blog link is dead, here's an archived version of it: https://web.archive.org/web/20200319071434/http://blog.whitehorses.nl/2010/03/17/oracle-11g-access-control-list-and-ora-24247/